# EditText behaving strange on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

See the following `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            EditText editText = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittextlayout, null);
            editText.setText("#" + i);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);

        }

    }

}
```

The layout `R.layout.activity_main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout `R.layout.edittext_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

After starting the app it looks like I would expect: every `EditText` being filled with it's index.

[image]

After rotating the device though, the `Activity` looks like this:

[image]

All the `EditText`s are there, but they all contain the same text.

What baffles me even more is that this **doesn't happen** when creating the `EditText`s programmatically with

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this)
```

instead of inflating it from a layout.

What's happening there?

You can check out my example and try for yourself [here](https://github.com/asco33/EditTextActingStrangeProject).

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005853/edittext-doubling-out-on-rotate) as in my case the text in the `EditText` does not double but get mixed up between different `EditText`s.

Comment: @B.Kemmer I dont know what you mean by 'runs into onResume'.

Comment: @B.Kemmer There is no further reference, the code I posted is complete, nothing left out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText doubling out on rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005853/edittext-doubling-out-on-rotate)

Comment: Are you using different xml for landscape and portrait?

Comment: @Amsheer Nope, just the layouts I posted.

Comment: I run your code with this android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  and it works. Is it working or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set some ID for each View.

For example:

```
view.setId(id);
```

Or use

```
onSaveInstanceState() - onRestoreInstanceState()
```

for saving info.

Comment: Clever idea. It can solve the problem I mentioned and prevent android from assigning wrong values to views.

Comment: Thanks, that actually prevents the effect from happening. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Ascorbin as I mentioned in my answer without the id's android assigns the last value it read to all views. To prevent that you can handle data yourself or set a different id to each view.

Comment: @Ascorbin It's related to inner mechanisms in android. It's a bug, I think.
On reCreate, manager can correctly identify only views with Ids. I think they have one field for one kind of view(or something like that) and last view rewrite it field on saving. So all same views receive that value on restore... IMHO.

Comment: @Tronum The views shouldn't even be retained though. After orientation change they should always be created 'from scratch', right?

Comment: @Ascorbin not in all times. It's true if your activity or fragment was recreated. 
But you can turn off that behaviour. Anyway I think that your problem was resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your activity recreates on every orientation and saved instance data handled wrong by Android. You can avoid it by setting an id to your dynamically created views or you can 
 Override onSaveInstanceState method to save your data like text in your edittexts and recover it on onCreate method like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check if we're recreating
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of edittext from saved state
            editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("edittext"));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("edittext", editText.getText().toString());
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

If you encounter any problem similar after doing this try to Override onRestoreInstanceState method to prevent android from doing your work.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: this is not tell the exact reason..he asking about duplicate of edittext settext